# Friendly URL with two properties?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite an ugly URL that's using two properties. For example, I want example.com/stories/?url=how-are-you?num=5 to be example.com/stories/how-are-you/5 I have rewritten the first property, but I don't know how to rewrite the num property. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stories/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?url=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stories/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?url=([^&\s]+)&num=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&num=$2 [L,QSA]
```